# What is "sleepwalking" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the best way to say 'to sleepwalk'? *Paŝi dormante*? *Dormiri*? *Dormpaŝi*? *Paŝdormi*?

Maybe something similar can be constructed for talking while sleeping too.

Answer (score 4):

*Somnambul'i* is to sleepwalk.

Which is derived from:

*Somnambul'o*

"*Homo nerve malsana, kiu dum dormo senkonscie k senmemore iras, parolas k agas, kvazaŭ li estus maldormanta k konscia*"

"A person nervously sick who, during sleep, unconsciously and without remembering, walks, speaks, and acts, as though they are awake and conscious."

http://vortaro.net/#somnambulo

Answer (score 4):

Your own suggestions are fine, although *dormiri* might be misunderstood as "to go to bed."

Easier alternatives to *somnambul-* are the adverbs *(dum)dorme, dormante* and the verb *dormvagi*:

- *Li parolis, gestis dumdorme.*
- *La bebo movadis siajn manojn dormante.*
- *Inter la aĝoj kvar kaj ok, mi ofte dormvagis.*

Comment: What is *dormvagi*? I cannot find it in PIV or ReVo…

Comment: From *dorm'* + *vagi*

Comment: *Dumdorme* strikes me as a little heavy and unnatural. I found two references in the Tekstaro - one was a reference to talking in ones sleep. The other was about doing something to someone in **their** sleep. It would be good to know if these words and examples are your own coinages or whether you picked them up somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

*Somnambulo* is the normal word for sleepwalker, and moderately common.  This gives us *somnambuli*.

I note that of your suggestions *dormiranto* is in actual use.

From *Al Torent*: *La urbo estas vigla dum la tago, tamen la taga vivo estas sonĝeca, similas al la agoj de **dormiranto**, La okuloj de la homoj estas pezaj kaj nebulecaj. Nur kiam vesperiĝas kaj ĉiuj stratoj brilas en la lumo de la malgrandaj sunoj, kiujn la homo mem kreis, komenciĝas la vera vivo.*